# Paver sealer options

Tags: pavers

So my question is more around what to do if I do not like my current paver sealer. So long story short, I went to the store and chose the pavers, they got installed in my house and I loved the way they looked. Now, comes the most frustrating part. I did put paver sealer on it and it was `color enhancing` paver sealer and now it looks like there is a `yellow stained` thin layer on it.

I absolutely despise it. I bought a `clear effect sealer` from the same brand and it looks amazing and now I really regret not trying each kind. Anyways, obviously, I would love to have a clear sealer on my pavers but now I already paid almost $700 on the sealer that is already on my pavers and I am just wondering what is the most cost effective way to get rid of this sealer. I am just calculating my options in my head and it sounds like I have options below?

1. Just ask my landscaping company to remove the sealer and re-apply another one. Which I think would be expensive because now I am paying for removal and re-application
2. Wait a few years for this `yellow film` to wear away. However, I am not confident if it would ever completely go away. My point is even after waiting 3-4 years, I still have to pay some money to have it completely removed then I may do it righ now.

Just confused. Any advice?

Comment: Are you sure you want to seal pavers? The one time I ask a landscaper, I was told not to.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. How would you seal the joint sand then?

Comment: polysand, or just don't. I'm sorry I cannot remember the reasoning.

Comment: There is zero reason to seal pavers. Polymeric sand should be used initially for any spaces between pavers, then reapplied/topped off annually. Polymeric sand will harden/lock into place once moistened properly.